# .sh script works in Terminal, but not when executed via "Run in Terminal"

Tags: bash, scripts, nautilus, jupyter

I'm getting nuts with this...

I want to be able to open the application "Jupyter Notebook" with a one line .sh script (that I have made executable) that simply says:

```
jupyter notebook
```

If I put this line directly in Terminal, it works. If I drag and drop the .sh script to Terminal, and hit enter, it works. But if I run the script from Nautilus and say "Run in Terminal" you see Terminal opening for the fraction of a second, and then nothing happens.

Help is much appreciated. Best, Khalo

//edit

I added "/bin/bash" to the end of the script, and now Terminal stays open, and I am able to see the error message that says:

> "/path_to_script/script.sh: 1: /path_to_script/script.sh: jupyter: not found"

Isn't this weird? As I said before, if typed directly into Terminal it works!

Comment: What if you replace your script with these two lines instead? `#!/bin/bash` `jupyter notebook & disown` - does that change anything?

Comment: What if you move your script straight to your home directory and then do the same thing?

Comment: @ByteCommander  Error message changes slightly to: "/path_to_script/script.sh: 3: jupyter: command not found"

Comment: @anonymous2 Didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: No, `#!/bin/bash` must be the very first line of your script. And the second line should be `jupyter notebook & disown` - nothing else.

Comment: @ByteCommander: Yeah, did that but not change!

Comment: Try restarting your PC to run script it worked for me

Comment: @user2104628: Restarted, but no help.

Comment: Where was the script before hand?  What was the path to it?

Comment: What is the output of `which jupyter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/$USER/.local/bin/jupyter notebook
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/jupyter notebook
```

If that still doesn't work, replace the path to jupyter with the output of the following command:

```
which jupyter
```

Comment: wouldn't `which` be more effective in this case? I get no path results with whereis on a known script, but which returns the full path to it's location in ~/bin...

Comment: This looks quite probable from my reading on the question.

Comment: @ElderGeek Jupyter installs with pip locally and returns a full path but it still won't run in nautilus like that. I have updated the script and I will look into which next time something like this comes up. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the script again as there was a typo. It should have $USER.

Comment: @mchid Your most welcome.

Comment: @mchid Thank you man, that solved it perfectly!!